# sql.Date using ebean. hh:mm:ss not included in MySQL table using util-date Date.getTime()

Tags: java, mysql, playframework-2.0, ebean

Im receiving util.Date 's from twitter4j getCreatedAt() method.

```
Date d = twitter.getCreatedAt();
System.out.println(d);
```

Out: 'Mon Feb 17 00:10:34 PST 2014'

I'm trying to convert that to a sql.Date *including* the time. With the code I'm using right now, querying mysql from terminal shows a date like:

```
2014-02-16 00:00:00
```

Here's the code in the Tweet Model. (Using Play 2, btw)

```
@Id
public long id;
@Formats.DateTime(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
public Date date;
```

When a status comes in I construct it like so:

```
this.date = new java.sql.Date(status.getCreatedAt().getTime());
```

I think it could possibly be something to do with the time zones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

java.sql.Date just keeps the normalized date, see this from Oracle documentation:

> To conform with the definition of SQL DATE, the millisecond values
>   wrapped by a java.sql.Date instance must be 'normalized' by setting
>   the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to zero in the
>   particular time zone with which the instance is associated.

If you want to use time with the date you have to use `java.sql.Timestamp` instead of `java.sql.Date`